# Asp.Net Core: Remove page from back button

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I have a register user page that has a form with client-side validation. When the form is submitted, if the Model State is invalid, it will show the form with the validation errors.

However, when I clicked the back button on the browser it goes to back to the form without the errors. When I click the back button again, it shows the previous page. Is there a way to go to the previous page when I click the back button once? Here is my code below:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Register()
{
    RegisterViewModel vm = new RegisterViewModel();
    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel vm)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser{UserName = vm.Username};
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, vm.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
            }
        }
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: You question is not clear. Please revise and provide more explanation about what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do some reading about the browser history API.  I do something similar when getting sorted versions of a page, each time replacing the previous page with the next one in the browser history using history.replaceState(null, "", newUrl);  But those are http gets and I'm not sure if the approach works for http posts. But it's something you may want to look into.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Let me try to give you more detail. I have this form to register users and it has some validation(required fields etc). If a user clicks a link to this form from the homepage, fills up the form and clicks submit and gets validation errors and for some reason decides to go back to homepage by clicking on the browser back button. In my case, when you click the back button, it renders the same registration form without the validation errors. When you click the back button a second time, it goes back to the homepage. I want to go back to the homepage on a single click.